# Почему на линуксе заикается звук и видео?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Относительно недавно начал использовать линукс. Но периодически у меня случается странный "баг", и плеер проигрывает часть дорожки, которую я слышал/видел несколько секунд назад.

Проблемы возникают не только в Rhithmbox но и в браузере от mozilla.
В VLC всё работает нормально. На Винде нет этой проблемы в том же браузере.

Вероятно, это проблема совместимости ПО Минта и моего железа.

Я переформулирую вопрос с того, что был изначально. Чтоб комфортно слушать и смотреть, мне нужно на всём моём потомке Убунту нормальное воспроизведение медиа. Желательно изменить настройки звука или системы, чтоб это исправить. Но если это проблема конкретно Firefox и
Rhithmbox, то буду искать другое по.

мой lscpu если надо

[image: мой lscpu]

Comment: этому процессору уже будет 10 лет. я правильно распознал?

Comment: да. Но на винде всё нормально работает.

Comment: У Вас слишком много неизвестно. Пробовали другие плееры/браузер? может просто диск старый, а у плеера нет достаточно приоритета.

Comment: @KoVadim пробовал

Comment: Тогда придется настраивать звуковую карту. Возможно, нужно поставить чуть больше буфер на воспроизведение

Comment: @KoVadim это надо настраивать для каждой карты отдельно?

Comment: иногда это очень индивидуально настраивается.

Comment: Пожалуйста не используйте метки таким образом. Здесь будет достаточно `linux`, `mint`, `linux-mint`

Comment: После продолжительного и упорного нетсталкинга я разобрался, как работают вместе /proc и /etc. Теперь размер буфера приравнивается с 128 каждый бут. Но проблема никуда не делась. Просто теперь такой баг происходит в два раза реже.

Comment: @KoVadim безопасно ли увеличивать буфер ещё в два раза?

Comment: А кто мешает попробовать? Я бы только USB флешку с livecd подготовил и вперёд к экспериментам.